# In Jquery ajax get the detail while entering in one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using MVC. In my one page, if i type one value that is process, if it exists the related details will populate in other all fields. how to do this in Ajax call?

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult GetDetail(string pincode)
   {
      Partner partner= null;
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pincode))
       {
           partner= _channelRepository.GetpartnerByPincode(pincode);
       }
       return View("Call",partner);
   }
```

Call is the Aspx page.

**In view:**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
            $('#getPincode').text('Get Pincode') // Sets text for company.
            .attr('href', '#');

            $("#getPincode").click(function () {
                $('#getPincode').text('Get Company')
            .attr('href', 'GetDetail?pincode=' + $('#Pincode').val());
            });

            $("#Pincode").blur(function () {
                $("#checkPincode").trigger('click');
            });


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#checkPincode').click(function () {
                    var name = $('#Pincode').val();
                    var data = 'pincode=' + name;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "GetDetail",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });

 </script>
```

But i don't know how to populate the result into my view which means editor fields???

**View:**

```
<%:Html.TextBox("Address")%>
```

Comment: The above code needs a little debugging:
1. In your Controller Class Print the value of pincode to see what values are passed
2.In your Controller class Check what data you are returning to View?

Comment: You need to return response as json result

Comment: You should use some debugging tools to help you.  You can use Firebug in Firefox - the 'Net' panel will tell you if your ajax url is being requested.  The Visual Studio debugger will tell you if the action method is being called - put a break point in `GetDetail()` and run the project in debug mode. These should really be your first efforts before asking a question.

Comment: I am getting result. but i don't know how to populate this result to the editor fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
public JsonResult GetDetail(string pincode)
   {
      Partner partner= null;
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pincode))
       {
           partner= _channelRepository.GetpartnerByPincode(pincode);
       }
       return Json(partner, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#checkPincode').click(function () {
                    var name = $('#Pincode').val();
                    var data = {'pincode': name};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/GetDetail",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

return it as a jsonResult

```
public JsonResult GetDetail(string pincode)
{
  Partner partner= null;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pincode))
   {
       partner= _channelRepository.GetpartnerByPincode(pincode);
   }
   return Json(partner);
}
```

or if you want to load partial view load it as

```
public ActionResult GetDetail(string pincode)
{
  Partner partner= null;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pincode))
   {
       partner= _channelRepository.GetpartnerByPincode(pincode);
   }
   return PartialView("Call",partner);
}

<div id="myDiv"></div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#checkPincode').click(function () {
                var name = $('#Pincode').val();
                var data = 'pincode=' + name;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "GetDetail",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                         $('#myDiv').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false
            });
        });
```

Comment: how to populate in view this result... that is  i am struggling?